# XSLT grouping data from 2 different tags and removing duplicates

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have this XML:

```
<CombinedResults>
    <Results>
        <Results>
                   <AccountNumber>5678</AccountNumber>
                   <Accounts>
                      <DomainAccount>
                         <AccountNumber>1234</AccountNumber>
                      </DomainAccount>
                      <DomainAccount>
                         <AccountNumber>9999</AccountNumber>
                      </DomainAccount>
                      <DomainAccount>
                        <AccountNumber>8888</AccountNumber>
                      </DomainAccount>
                    </Accounts>
       </Results>
       <Results>
             <AccountNumber>0427</AccountNumber>
       </Results>
       <Results>
               <AccountNumber>1234</AccountNumber>
               <Accounts>
                  <DomainAccount>
                    <AccountNumber>5678</AccountNumber>
                  </DomainAccount>
                  <DomainAccount>
                    <AccountNumber>9999</AccountNumber>
                  </DomainAccount>
                  <DomainAccount>
                    <AccountNumber>8888</AccountNumber>
                  </DomainAccount>
              </Accounts>
       </Results>
</Results>
</CombinedResults>
```

I need to create a table where each row has the AccountNumber value. The table must contains both the values from the Results/AccountNumber tag and the values from Results/Accounts/DomainAccount/AccountNumber tag and also no duplicates.

I managed to do it, but I was not able to remove the duplicates.

My code was:

```
<xsl:for-each select="CombinedResults/Results/Results">
<tr>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="AccountNumber"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="CombinedResults/Results/Results/Accounts/DomainAccount">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="AccountNumber"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I need to get the values from the Results tag first, and then the ones from DomainAccount, with no duplicates.
This is the output I need to get:

```
<tr>
   <td>5678</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>0427</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1234</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>9999</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8888</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output you want in **XSLT-1.0**, you have to use a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](https://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). So create an `xsl:key` with all of your values and then select only the first item in an `xsl:for-each`.

An XSLT-1.0 stylesheet realizing that is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="items" match="Results/Results/AccountNumber | Results/Results/Accounts/DomainAccount/AccountNumber" use="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="/CombinedResults">
        <xsl:for-each select="//AccountNumber[generate-id() = generate-id(key('items',text())[1])]">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">                                        
                    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="."/> -->
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="key('items',text())[parent::Results]">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="key('items',text())[parent::Results]"/>                          
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="key('items',text())[not(parent::Results)]"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">5678</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">1234</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">9999</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">8888</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">0427</td>
</tr>
```

The order is not as you mentioned, but I cannot infer any ordering system from your desired output. Use an `xsl:sort` in the `xsl:for-each` loop if you need another order.

---

In **XSLT-2.0** this is easier. You would just use the `xsl:for-each-group` function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/CombinedResults">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Results/Results/AccountNumber | Results/Results/Accounts/DomainAccount/AccountNumber" group-by="text()">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">                                        
                    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]"/> -->
                    <xsl:value-of select="if (current-group()[name(..) = 'Results']) then current-group()[name(..) = 'Results'][1] else current-group()[name(..) != 'Results'][1]"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Another question - how can I make it select the data from Results/Results first? For example, if the AccountNumber 1234 from Results has some other subtags, and the one in DomainAccount has some different data, how do I make sure it selects the one from Results/Results and remove the one from DomainAccount?

Comment: I added two solutions - one for XSLT-1.0 and the other for XSLT-2.0. You can use the new XSLT-1.0 part in XSLT-2.0 if it would better fit your needs. Essentially, both code samples introduce a distinction between elements with a parent `Results` and otherwise. The first choice is preferred.